# On strong resolvent convergence of unbounded operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Given a sequence of unbounded self-adjoint operators $\Delta_N$ defined on some fixed domain of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ converging to  i*identity in the sense that: for all $\phi\in\mathcal{H}$ one has
$\|((\Delta_N-i)^{-1}-i\mathrm{Id})\phi\|\to 0$, as $N\to\infty$.

Denoting by $R_{\Delta_N}(i)=(\Delta_N-i)^{-1}$ the (bounded) resolvent operator of $\Delta_N$. Given an  positive multiplication operator $V\in L_{\mathrm{loc}}^2(\mathbb{R})$ which blows up if $|x|\to\infty$. Does it hold that

$(\mathrm{Id}+VR_{\Delta_N}(i))^{-1}$ converges strongly to $(i(V-i))^{-1}$,

assuming that the domain of $\Delta_N$ is contained in the domain of $V$ ?

Thank you in advance